# Issues in Creating Custom Search Box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a custom search box. Please see code below.

**Problem 1:** The input element (although not visible) in the figure below appears to be above the search icon before it is clicked (see green circle). How can I place both as inline? Note: The layout of the blue container was created using flexbox.

[image: unwanted space above the search icon].

**Problem 2:** In the image below, on clicking the search icon, a space appears between the input element and the icon element (see green circle in section 3). Is it a result of the flexbox property? How can I get rid of it?

[image: space between search box and search icon]

**Problem 3:** I need help in perfectly aligning the contact details in section 1 (see image in problem 2) with their corresponding icons. The phone numbers and email address appear to be at the bottom of the icons instead of center.

Thank you!

```css
body {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  /* font-size: 1.2em; */
  background: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* PRE TOP NAVIGATION BAR */
.preTopNav {
  background-color: navy;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.preTopNav-Items {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.preTopNav-Items img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.preTopNav-Items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.preTopNav .contactDetails,
.preTopNav .socialDetails {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.preTopNav .search {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: navy;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 10px 4px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: width 0.5s;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: mone;
}

.preTopNav .search img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.preTopNav .search.active {
  width: 300px;
}

.preTopNav .search input {
  /* margin-right: 50px; */
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
  width: calc(100%-50px);
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* PHOTO SLIDESHOW */

/* MEDIA QUERIES */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home BGS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/718022a53c.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- PRE TOP NAVIGATION BAR -->
    <div class="preTopNav">
      <div class="preTopNav-Items contactDetails">
        <div class="contactDetails-Items">
          <img src="https://www.telegram.org/img/t_logo.png" alt="" />
          <a href="tel:+2348056710255">+2348056710255</a>
        </div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="contactDetails-Items">
          <img src="https://www.telegram.org/img/t_logo.png" alt="" />
          <a href="tel:012911722">012911722</a>
        </div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="contactDetails-Items">
          <img src="https://www.telegram.org/img/t_logo.png" alt="" />
          <a href="info@bethelgeminischools.com"
            >info@bethelgeminischools.com</a
          >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="preTopNav-Items socialDetails">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bethelgeminischools"
          ><img
            src="/Icons/Facebook (Transparent - White Outline).png"
            alt=""
        /></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/bethelgeminischools"
          ><img
            src="/Icons/Twitter (Transparent - White Outline).png"
            alt=""
        /></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bethelgeminischools"
          ><img
            src="/Icons/Instagram (Transparent - White Outline).png"
            alt=""
        /></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/bethelgeminischools"
          ><img
            src="/Icons/LinkedIn (Transparent - White Outline).png"
            alt=""
        /></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://www.wa.me/2348056710255"
          ><img
            src="/Icons/Whatsapp (Transparent - White Outline).png"
            alt=""
        /></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://www.t.me/bethelgeminischools"
          ><img
            src="/Icons/Telegram (Transparent - White Outline).png"
            alt=""
        /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="preTopNav-Items search">
        <input type="text" class="searchBar" placeholder="Search..." />
        <img
          class="searchIcon"
          src="https://www.telegram.org/img/t_logo.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".searchIcon").click(function () {
          $(".search").toggleClass("active");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please don't *shout* in your title

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm sorry. It wasn't on purpose.

Comment: All good -no harm done :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your HTML and use the flexbox efficiently.

[Complete guide to CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) | [Media Query for Responsive design](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```js
$(".searchIcon").click(function() {
  $(".search").toggleClass("active");
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

.preTopNav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: navy;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

.contactDetails {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.contactDetails a {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.contactDetails a:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.contactDetails a img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.socialDetails {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.socialDetails a {
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.search {
  width: 18%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.searchBar {
  display: none;
}

.search.active .searchBar {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .preTopNav {
    flex-direction: column
  }
  .socialDetails {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .search {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .contactDetails a {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .contactDetails {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preTopNav">
  <div class="preTopNav-Items contactDetails">
    <a href="tel:+2348056710255"><img src="https://placehold.it/24x24" alt="" /><span>+2348056710255M</span></a>
    <a href="tel:012911722"><img src="https://placehold.it/24x24" alt="" /><span>012911722</span></a>
    <a href="info@bethelgeminischools.com"><img src="https://placehold.it/24x24" alt="" /><span>info@bethelgeminischools.com</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="preTopNav-Items socialDetails">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bethelgeminischools"><img src="https://placehold.it/24x24" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/bethelgeminischools"><img src="https://placehold.it/24x24" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bethelgeminischools"><img src="https://placehold.it/24x24" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/bethelgeminischools"><img src="https://placehold.it/24x24" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="https://www.wa.me/2348056710255"><img src="https://placehold.it/24x24" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="https://www.t.me/bethelgeminischools"><img src="https://placehold.it/24x24" alt="" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="preTopNav-Items search">
    <input type="text" class="searchBar" placeholder="Search..." />
    <img class="searchIcon" src="https://placehold.it/24x24" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can accept this as answer if it helped you to fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:
If you add `display: flex` to the parent div container the items will displayed in a grid like view.

Problem 2: The gap is caused by right css attribute. Also note that when using calc you need to add a space between the operator

```
.preTopNav .search input {
  position: relative;
  right: 50px; <-- This is causing the space/gap between the search box and icon
  width: calc(100% - 50px); <-- Added space before and after minus 
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Problem 3: Make the parent containers display flex and add `align-items: center` to align properly.

```
.contactDetails-Items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

I've [created a Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-grothendieck-xsqo7?file=/index.html) where you can see the final result.